# Where is the Material Components Catalog app?

Tags: android, material-design

The (so far) insufficient documentation for Material Design / components says this

> To try out the MDC Catalog app, you can either run the catalog module
>   in Android Studio or run the following Gradle command:
>   ./gradlew :catalog:installDebug

However, I can ont find the "catalog module" in Android Studio, nor am I sure where to run that Gradle command.

Finally, there is no catalog app in GitHub for Android although there is a "catalog app" for the web components.

Comment: The question about how to run the Gradle command haven't been address yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The catalog app is located in the [material-components-android repo](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/catalog).

Comment: How did you find it!!

Answer (score 1):

For [Material Components Catalog app](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/catalog-app), you can get the source code at [material-components/material-components-android on GitHub](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android), the source link is mentioned in the [official Building from source](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/building-from-source) page, pre-built binary can be downloaded from their [GitHub release](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases) page.

---

I'm searching for Jetpack Compose Catalog and Google search bought me here, for people looking for Jetpack Compose Catalog which contains the official Material components for Jetpack Compose, you can get the app on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=androidx.compose.material.catalog). For source code, you can view the source code on AOSP using [Android Code Search](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/integration-tests/material-catalog/) or [the synchronized Android Jetpack repository on GitHub](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/tree/androidx-main/compose/material/material/integration-tests/material-catalog). ([reference](https://material.io/blog/jetpack-compose-catalog))

Personally, I recommend using [Android Code Search](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/integration-tests/material-catalog/) since the Compose Material Catalog app also relies on code in some other source repository (e.g. the source code for [ButtonSample](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/samples/src/main/java/androidx/compose/material/samples/ButtonSamples.kt;l=1?q=ButtonSamples.kt&sq=) are in package `androidx.compose.material.samples.*`), and the search option provided by Android Code Search can be very helpful to find the actual code you're looking for.